# MAX on a VIEW doing a TableScan instead of using metadata lookup. Why doesn't SF use metadata?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I noticed even the simplest 'SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM MYVIEW' is somewhat slow (taking minutes) in my environment, and found it's doing a TableScan of 100+GB across 80K micropartitions.

My expectation was this to finish in milliseconds using MIN/MAX/COUNT metadata in each micropartitions. In fact, I do see Snowflake finishing the job in milliseconds using metadata for almost same MIN/MAX value lookup in following article:

http://cloudsqale.com/2019/05/03/performance-of-min-max-functions-metadata-operations-and-partition-pruning-in-snowflake/

Is there any limitation in how Snowflake decides to use metadata? Could it be because I'm querying through a view, instead of querying a table directly?

=== Added for clarity ===

Thanks for answering! Regarding how the view is defined, it seems to adds a WHERE clause for additional filtering with a cluster key. So I believe it should still be possible to fully use metadata of miropartitions. But as posted, TableScan is being done in profilter output.

I'm bit concerned on your comment on SecureView. The view I'm querying is indeed a SECURE VIEW - does it affect how optimizer handles my query? Could that be a reason why TableScan is done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running the query on a **view**. The metadata you're referring to will be used when you're running a simple MIN MAX etc on the table, however if you have some logic inside your view which requires filtering / joining of data then Snowflake cannot return results just based off the metadata.

So yes, you are correct when you say the following because your view is probably doing something other than a simple MAX on the table:

> ...Could it be because I'm querying through a view, instead of querying a table directly?

Comment: Querying a view should not affect using the metadata unless it is a secure view (I believe the optimizer expands non-secure views).  But any restriction on the result set (JOIN, WHERE etc) would require data access.

Comment: My assumption was that the view had some logic in it (predicates / joins etc) otherwise Taisuke would probably just be querying the table.

Comment: Updated my answer based off Hans' comment.